# How to downscale a landcover dataset with a 300m x 300x resolution in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, math, geospatial, netcdf

I have a netcdf file of landcover for a year with 300m resolution.
This is too detailed and I want to downscale this to about 3k.

At the moment I am opening the `.nc` file with `xarray`
This gives me a dataset with:

`Dimensions: time: 1 lat: 64800 lon: 129600 bounds: 2`

It also has a lot of variables...the only one I'm interested in is `lccs_class (time, lat, lon)`

I drop the unneeded variables with:

```
ds = ds.drop(['processed_flag', 'current_pixel_state', 'observation_count', 'change_count', 'crs', 'time_bounds'])
```

I want to look at a specific 1x1 degree block - so I set it up like this:

```
central_lat = -33.9248685
central_lon = 18.4240553

lat_min = central_lat - 0.5
lat_max = central_lat + 0.5

lon_min = central_lon - 0.5
lon_max = central_lon + 0.5
filtered_ds = ds.sel(lat=slice(lat_max, lat_min), lon=slice(lon_min, lon_max))
```

And I convert it to a pandas dataframe:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 259200 entries, (Timestamp('2019-01-01 00:00:00'), -33.42638888888889, 17.92638888888891, 0) to (Timestamp('2019-01-01 00:00:00'), -34.42361111111111, 18.923611111111114, 1)
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column      Non-Null Count   Dtype  
---  ------      --------------   -----  
 0   lccs_class  259200 non-null  uint8  
 1   lat_bounds  259200 non-null  float64
 2   lon_bounds  259200 non-null  float64
dtypes: float64(2), uint8(1)
memory usage: 5.7 MB
```

I want to zoom out to see `3000mx3000m` representative blocks instead.

There must be a known technique to do this?

I'm thinking of the following approach:

Take the middle point of 9 blocks: Where block is slected(x) when `(row - 1) % 3 == 0`

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 x 0 0 x 0 0 x 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 x 0 0 x 0 0 x 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 x 0 0 x 0 0 x 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

And then choose the dominant `lccs_class` in the surrounding blocks. But what if there are equal amounts?

I'm also not sure how to calculate the x block and the surrounding ones from the dataset.

Comment: You're missing a crucial bit of detail: what do you expect that 3000x3000 slice to represent? Do you just want a point sample (i.e just throw everything away and pick every 10th element), some convolved/averaged value, or even something else entirely?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple slicing with [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
sub_df = df.iloc[1::3, 1::3]
```

Output:

```
   1  4  7
1  x  x  x
4  x  x  x
7  x  x  x
```

Used input:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
1  0  x  0  0  x  0  0  x  0
2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
4  0  x  0  0  x  0  0  x  0
5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
6  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
7  0  x  0  0  x  0  0  x  0
8  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

For a more generic method, if you consider`N*N` squares, `N` being odd:

```
N = 3
start = N//2

sub_df = df.iloc[start::N, start::N]
```

###### most common value per square

you can use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) for reshaping, and [`scipy.stats.mode`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mode.html#scipy.stats.mode) to get the most common value:

```
from scipy.stats import mode

N = 3
start = N//2

out = pd.DataFrame(mode(df.to_numpy().reshape(N, df.shape[0]//N, N, df.shape[1]//N)
                          .swapaxes(1, 2)
                          .reshape(N, N, -1),
                        axis=-1).mode.squeeze(axis=-1),
                   columns=df.columns[start::N], index=df.index[start::N]
                  )
```

Output:

```
   1  4  7
1  a  b  0
4  0  0  0
7  0  0  0
```

Used input:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
0  a  a  a  b  0  0  0  0  0
1  a  x  a  b  x  b  0  x  0
2  x  x  x  b  0  x  0  0  0
3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
4  0  x  0  0  x  0  0  x  0
5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
6  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
7  0  x  0  0  x  0  0  x  0
8  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: Thanks. That will help get the final values, but I would still need a way to figure out what each x should be based on the surrounding blocks.

Comment: @DiMi then I'm not sure I follow you entirely, can you provide a less ambiguous example with input and matching expected output?

Comment: So all the zeros are specific land cover classes, ie: water, urban etc. There are too many, I want to downscale the resolution. My thinking is to take the middle of a group and have that block's value be the dominant value in the 3x3 group. The zeros are just to show the shape of the grid.

Comment: This looks good. Now I will just need to work on the original dataframe to get it into this shape. One question...Will this take into account the value of block x as well? So if x is a, it will add that? And what if there are equal amount of a, b and c?

Comment: @DiMi you can do many things, but I cannot guess the logic you have in mind. The above approach finds the list common value among each 3x3 block. Please update your question with a meaningful example to better illustrate the expected logic.

Answer (score -2):

To downscale a landcover dataset with a 300m x 300m resolution using pandas and the provided code, you can follow these steps:

Resample the Dataset:
You can use the resample method provided by xarray to downscale the dataset to your desired resolution. In this case, you want to resample to a 300m x 300m resolution. You can achieve this by specifying the lat and lon factors in the resample method.

```
resampled_ds = filtered_ds.resample(lat=0.0027, lon=0.0027).mean()
```

Convert to Pandas DataFrame:
If you want to work with the resampled data in a Pandas DataFrame, you can convert the xarray dataset to a DataFrame using the to_dataframe method.

```
df = resampled_ds.to_dataframe()
```

Optional: Filter Out NaN Values:
Depending on the original dataset and the resampling process, you may have NaN values in the resulting DataFrame. You can choose to filter out rows with NaN values if needed.

```
df = df.dropna()
```

Now you have a Pandas DataFrame (df) that contains the landcover data downscaled to a 300m x 300m resolution within the specified latitude and longitude bounds. You can perform further data analysis or visualization on this DataFrame as needed.

Comment: Is this answer AI-generated? This is nonsense, `resample` doesn't have such parameters…